# "invalid literal for int() with base 10:" error while changing DateTimeField to DateField in models.py | Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to show how many posts are being made each day so i wrote this code:

```
class ServerInsightsView(View):
    def get(self, request, server_tag):
        server = Server.objects.get(tag=server_tag)
        post_daily_count =server.posts.all().values('created').annotate(dailycount=Count('created')).order_by() #to get the number of posts each day depending on the DateTimeField
        return render(request, 'servers/insights.html', {'server':server, 'post_daily_count': post_daily_count})
```

This code is working but since `created` is a `DateTimeField` it groups the data **depending on both date and time** so for example (2022, 11, 15, 16, 24, 10, 577648) and (2022, 11, 15, 16, 40, 39, 224605)
are in the same day but in different `Time`.

so in order to fix this i've changed `DateTimeField` to `DateField`:

**Here is the models.py:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    saved = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='saves')
    upvotes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='upvotes')
    downvotes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='downvotes')
    votes_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    server = models.ForeignKey(Server, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts', null=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True) #was DateTimeField
    updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True) #was DateTimeField
```

and now i get this error after this change:

**invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'15 16:24:10.577648'**

Comment: Not fix to your error, but couldn't you Extract date from datetime in annotation and group by that?

Comment: have you migrated correctly after changing

Comment: @ManojTolagekar yes I've migrated after making those changes

Comment: @TrueGopnik could you please explain more?

Comment: I explained in answer to use code formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotating date and grouping by that using TruncDate:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate


class ServerInsightsView(View):
def get(self, request, server_tag):
    server = Server.objects.get(tag=server_tag)
    post_daily_count = (
        server.posts.all()
        .annotate(date=TruncDate('created'))
        .values('date')
        .annotate(dailycount=Count('date'))
        .order_by()
    )
    return render(
        request,
        'servers/insights.html',
        {'server': server, 'post_daily_count': post_daily_count},
    )
```